# skipping comments with regex

Tags: regex, comments

this has been asked so many times - yet I don't get why the following negative look-behind *still matches* after the comment character ";" ?!

```
   (?<!;).+mylib.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aTkMKng6LFhTLK4b)

TEST-TEXT:

```
;   /home/mylib/blabla/laydef1.rul (matches wrongly!?)

/home/mylib/blabla/laydef2.rul (matches as it should)
```

P.S. RegEx class is PCRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PCRE doesn't support variable length lookbehind you can use this regex construct:

```
/^\h*(?:;.*(*SKIP)(*F)|.*mylib.*)/m
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vN9xB2/1)

Your regex: `(?<!;).+mylib.*` fails because `.+` matches everything from `; to`mylib`

- `(*FAIL)` behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`
- `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` together provide a nice alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehind in above regex.

Comment: thank you very much for the time you took to explain it so prudently!